# using event.target vs selecting the element

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a difference between working a property of an element through the `event.target` vs *working it directly*?

I don't understand if there's any difference.

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  console.log(e.target.value);
  //vs
  console.log(btn.value);
}
```

Is there a better practice when doing this?

Comment: Not really, you can use them interchangeably.

Comment: @Konrud only if there are no element children of the `<button>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an important difference. The `event.target` property tells you what element was involved with the creation of the event. For a "click", it's the element that was under the cursor when the "click" happened.

Thus if your HTML looked like:

```
<button><span>Text</span><img src="something.jpg"></button>
```

a click on the button content would trigger the event from either the `<span>` or the `<img>`, and one of those elements would be the target.

There's another event property, `event.currentTarget`, that is always a reference to the element to which the event handler is attached. That's probably what you want. Alternatively, if you bind handlers with `.addEventListener()`, then the value of `this` when the handler is invoked will be a reference to the same thing as `currentTarget`.

Comment: Yeah good remark, though `this` might be better, because (nitpick), `currentTarget` is not *always a reference to the element to which the event handler is attached*, it is the element on which the current phase the event occurs, if e.g you do `elem.onclick = e => { setTimeout(()=>console.log(e.currentTarget)); }`, you'll get `null`.

Comment: @Kaiido well yes that would fail, but it doesn't make any sense because a timeout handler is not a DOM event handler and there's no event object involved.

Comment: No you don't get my point, sorry I alluded too much in my previous comment I meant `elem.onclick = e => { setTimeout(()=>console.log(e.currentTarget)); }`

Comment: @Kaiido that said, you're right that `this` would also work.

Comment: ah I see what you mean. Yes that would clearly not work properly.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you're selecting an element by ID. Your reference is the same as the `target` so there is no difference. A lot of time we use [delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) so you might not have reference to the clicked element. Hence we use `target` from the `event` object.

Worth also to check target vs [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)